# Compare an iteration with the next and next next iteration

Tags: python, iteration

I have a dataframe with three columns (Site, EventTime, EndTime), and I need to compare the first item on Site with the next and the next value. If those three are different, I need to copy the endTime of the last one into the first one.

[image: Original DF]

I tried this:

```
i = 0

while i <= len(df): 
    if df['Site'][i] != df['Site'][i+1] and df['Site'][i] != df['Site'][i+2]:
        df['EndTime'][i]=df['EndTime'][i+2]
        i = i+2
    if df['Site'][i] != df['Site'][i+1]:
        df['EndTime'][i]=df['EndTime'][i+1]
        i = i+1


    i = i+1
```

and it gave this error:

```
C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_19504\3633764966.py:5: SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  df['EndTime'][i]=df['EndTime'][i+2]
Output exceeds the size limit. Open the full output data in a text editor
```

I need to replace the endTime whith the last endTime when the next two iterations are different from each other:

What I need:
[image: What I need]

Comment: done, sorry this is my first post.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Why on index 8 you have give value to first a, unlike reset where you are giving value to the last a?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I am assuming you need to set the new time on all `last record of site a`, with the next first record of `site c EndTime.`

Followinglly, I have used lambda function to pass through line by line, and check condintion, where give true if **current site and next row site is different** and **current site is a**, if yes then get the first value of c Endtime in **remain** in loop data, or else take None.

Try following Code:

```
import numpy as np
df['new time'] = df[:-1].apply(lambda r: df[r.name:].loc[df['site']=='c'].groupby(['site']).first()['EndTime'].values[0]
              if (df.at[r.name,'site']!=df.at[r.name+1,'site'] and r.site=='a') else np.nan, axis=1)
df
```